# Is it possible to compact and/or compress a pst from the command line / powershell?

Tags: outlook

We've got loads of psts sitting on a network drive that is running short of space.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt find much info on using Powershell to compact PST's, but I did find an app called PSTcompactor.  Looks like it was available at one time from a company called GFI as a standalone app, but is now bundled with some other software.

I found the standalone with a quick Google search.

I have to add that I have never used this software and know nothing at all about it and could not recommend it one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any command line utilities that will do this in the way you appear to want.  Just having the PST open in Outlook, while sitting idle, should automatically compact them.

If that won't work, you could VBA script out a manual compression of each PST/OST file.  See the instructions here:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/scriptingVisualBasicscript/Jan2006/post25027139.asp

Comment: this link: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/scriptingVisualBasicscript/Jan2006/post25027139.asp is dead

Comment: The compact when idle does not work if the user is accessing the pst file on an RDS server, as the RDS server is never idle.

Answer (score 1):

Worth making the distinction between compressing and compacting re. PST files.
Compacting removes empty space within the file, and thus reduces its size. Using NTFS compression (as the VBScript link above seems to do) will make the file use less space on the disk, but the wasted space within the file is still there.
As far as I can tell there is no way to compact a PST file other than using a 3rd party utility (of which there seems to be a few).